# Meaning of the array returned by the activation function GELU (Vision Transformer)

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to understand VisionTransformer (ViT) and in the basic implementation it uses GELU activation function inside the MLP, that is the last layer.

What is the meaning of the vector given back by the function?

In my project I have 4 classes [0,50,80,100] and given an x (an image) I'm using the highest value of the array give back by the MLP (so the GELU) that is something that looks like:
[-0.00404951, -0.15865529,  0.        ,  0.8413447 ,  2.9959507 ]
to do classification.

Can i do classification in this way? Taking the index of the highest value and then classify the x in input with that index?
Is the vector given back by the GELU in the range of values [-3,3]?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The softmax function is not necessarily needed during inference, so the output of the GELU can be used for classification.
If you need a probabilistic representation, you can use the softmax function to convert the GELU output to [0, 1].

For example, if you input the output of GELU in question into the softmax function, you will get the following values, but the index of the largest value will not change.

```
In [1]: import tensorflow as tf
In [2]: tf.nn.softmax([-0.00404951, -0.15865529, 0.0, 0.8413447, 2.9959507])
Out[2]:
<tf.Tensor: shape=(5,), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([0.0395644 , 0.03389692, 0.03972494, 0.09214137, 0.7946724 ],
      dtype=float32)>
```